# AWS Route 53 DNS fail after transfer

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, routes, cname

I've transferred my domain name from GoDaddy to Route53 but it seems to have broken the DNS configurations such as Gmail and other subdomains...

The domain is not owned by GoDaddy anymore but by AWS.

I don't understand the name servers settings and I tried to configure the Gmail MX but without success...

Here is a screenshot of my current configuration:
[AWS Route 53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhKrl.png)

I can't to receive my emails anymore so it's a bit scary!!
What do I need to do to fix it?
The domain name is: nummermusic.com
Thanks,
Silvere

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:
In the Registered Domain preference panel you have a Name Servers configuration option. It was set with weird values:
ns23.domaincontrol.com
ns24.domaincontrol.com

REplace it with the 4 Name Servers provided by Route 53 and it will be fine

Answer (score 0):

Your domain record is still showing that it's using GoDaddy for DNS:

```
$ dig nummermusic.com NS

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> nummermusic.com NS
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 22187
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;nummermusic.com.       IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
nummermusic.com.    86400   IN  NS  ns23.domaincontrol.com.
nummermusic.com.    86400   IN  NS  ns24.domaincontrol.com.
```

You'll want to change the registration for your domain to no longer use the nameservers `ns23.domaincontrol.com` and `ns24.domaincontrol.com` but to instead use the AWS ones shown in your snapshot.  Go into AWS -> Route 53 -> Registered Domains, select nummermusic.com, and update the Name Servers there.

Comment: Thanks a lot that really helps.